# Invalid typecast error processing JsonResult in Delphi

Tags: arrays, json, delphi

I have the JSON below:

```json
{
    "value": "[{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value3\"}]",
    "formatters": [],
    "contentTypes": [],
    "declaredType": null,
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

I need to get hold of `value` as an array using Delphi.

```pascal
var
  obj2: TJSonObject;
  arr:  TJSONArray;
```

The overall JSON is an object, so I first do:

```pascal
 obj2 := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(strJSon) as TJSONObject;
```

I then need to get the `value` part as an array, so I use:

```pascal
arr := obj2.GetValue('value') as TJSONArray;
```

I get an `Invalid Class Typecast` error on the line above.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: In the JSON you have shown, `value` is NOT an array (`TJSONArray`), it is a string instead (`TJSONString`), hence the cast error. Note the quote chars surrounding the `value`'s data.  If it were a true array, those quotes would not be present.

Comment: Ok that makes sense is there a best practice way to decide this so that it can become an array?

Comment: `value` is a string in the JSON, period.  The JSON has no concept of what the string represents.  You will have to parse the string yourself to make your own array from it.  I suppose the simplest approach would be to retrieve the string and pass it to another `ParseJSONValue()` call, and cast the resulting `TJSONValue` to `TJSONArray`.

Comment: Yuk this in reality could become a very big string with a lot of elements in it. The objects inside have a lot of properties

Comment: Why is JSON data being stringified at all? What is the `value` supposed to represent exactly?

Comment: Because it’s being generated from a web api call that is using new jsonresult I’m trying to ensure that I can parse the data in a client like Delphi when calling a method that wraps the response in a new jsonresult object

Comment: I seriously doubt any web API would want to encode JSON data *inside* of a JSON string like you have shown. It sounds like maybe the website is not using `JsonResult` correctly, sending a *stringified* version of an object instead of sending the object itself.

Comment: When the web api uses new Json result this is what it comes back with I’m not sure the correct time to use new Jsonresult

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181513/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this transformation to your StrJson variable, before doing the typecast

```
Uses StrUtils;

Var
strJson: String;

strJson:= ReplaceStr(strJson,'"[','[');
strJson:= ReplaceStr(strJson,']"',']');
strJson:= ReplaceStr(strJson,'\"','"');
vJSonArray:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(strJson) as TJSONArray; //OK
```

Comment: The format in which you get the JSON is not valid, or at least it is not what you expect.
The text: "value": "[{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value3\"}]"
means you has created the entry with something like: ObjJson.AddPair(String, String)
but, instead you should use: ObjJson.AddPair(String, TJSOnArray)

The following example is valid, but the value is not an array, but a string
MyValue:= '[{"field1":"Value1"}]';
ObjJson.AddPair('value', MyValue);

This is the one you are looking for:
ObjJson.AddPair(Texto, TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(MyValue) as TJSONArray)

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON you have shown, the `value` field is a *string*, not an *array*.  That is why you are getting the cast error.  Had it been an *actual* array, it would have looked like this instead:

```json
"value": [{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3"}],
```

Note the surrounding quotes are gone, and the inner quotes are not escaped as `\"`.

If you know that the `value` string represents a JSON array, you can access the array like this:

```pascal
var
  val1, val2: TJSONValue;
  obj: TJSONObject;
  arr: TJSONArray;
begin
  val1 := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(strJSon);
  try
    obj := val1 as TJSONObject;
    val2 := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(obj.GetValue('value').Value);
    try
      arr := val2 as TJSONArray;
      // use arr as needed ...
    finally
      val2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    val1.Free;
  end;
end;
```